# Breakpoints Not Applying Float Rule After Resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For some reason, setting up breakpoints with a float rule doesn't seem to be applying when you change the width of your screen.  Check out this simple example:

```css
.left-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 130px;
}

.right-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 160px;
}

@media (min-width:750px) {
  .left-content {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .right-content {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-content">This is some text!</div>
      <div class="right-content">
        <button>Click me!</button>
        <button>Click me 2!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

When you first load this on a large screen, the buttons and text are correctly aligned.  Once you make the screen smaller to the point the original rules are applied (IE `display: block;` is triggered), the buttons will not float correctly when expanding your screen.

Are floats broken when using responsive breakpoints?

([JSBin link](http://output.jsbin.com/vugimafitu) so you can more easily test what I'm describing, seems the preview button is breaking the example snippet.)

### Edit

This appears to only be broken in Google Chrome.  Are there any resources on how to get this working, or should I rely on another technique to have these buttons be on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are saying and I am not sure why this happens.

But to fix it, you can add a "float:left" to your "div.left-content" when the screen is less than 750px.

Comment: Sure enough, that did fix it.